# How to set permernent dbpath for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I understand that mongo db need to be started before I can interact with it. But what I don't understand why do I set the dbpath every time? I thought we only need to configure that path once. Am I correct?

Comment: Not looking into videos... the standard mongodb startup script read their configuration from a file under /etc where you can clearly configure the dbpath. What is the problem here? Apart from that: the link is not working

Comment: Why was this tagged with node.js? There is zero relation with node.js in your question.

Comment: What OS you are using? If it's *nix then you can configure dbpath and other mongodb options by editing `/etc/mongodb.conf` file.

Comment: @leonid I'm using mac OS. there's no mongodb.conf in the downloaded folder for mac OS

Comment: @CRUSADER you mean the mac os system etc folder? Because there's no etc in mongo download package for mac os

Comment: There is if you install it using homebrew instead of downloading it directly from the site, you must download from repo to get the init.d job

Comment: Using homebrew is the right way to install mongodb on mac OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this two ways:

- change your dbpath to the hard coded one which will point to `/data/db/`
- Or make a startup script that will actually call the MongoDB instance for you

You could make a few scripts, as I said in my last point, to do this for you, as an example:

```
=== rnMongo.sh ===
./mongod --dbpath
```

Then with a single command:

```
./rnMongo.sh
```

Or as an upstart job:

```
# mongodb - Mongo Starter
author "lol"
description "Starts the MongoDB servers"

start on started network-services

#expect fork
exec /home/ubuntu/mongodb/bin/mongod --auth
#echo "Mongodb is now running";
#exit 0;
#stop
stop on runlevel [016]

#pre-stop
```

Something along those lines

Answer (score 3):

Just add mongod --dbpath /home/user/mongodb to your startup applications ;)

Answer (score 1):

sudo mongod  --port  portnumber  --dbpath   /path to your folder

By default it is set to
sudo mongod  --port  27017   --dbpath   /var/lib/mongodb

Comment: how do you do this for setting mongo service?  Can you set a path for service mongo start command?

Comment: You can do this in config file